# Searching Gmail from Python

Tags: python, gmail

I am trying to write a script to search my gmail. I have followed the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) guide and got that working and played with altering that with other API calls. When I follow the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering) for searching it shows, not API as for getting labels, sending messages etc call but just a simple GET request. This of course does not work with a simple request

```
response = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=in:sent after:2014/01/01 before:2014/02/01')
```

Just returns unauthorised. This doesn't surprise me given the other examples.

What am I missing? Is the documentation out of date (my intuition) is there a way to do a simple with request with the authorisation that is used by the API?

I.e. This authorisation as used by the quick start example

```
if os.path.exists("token.json"):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
```

I don't seem to be unable to find a example of this use case with a simple GET.

Comment: Please edit your question and an example there's not enough code here

Comment: google does not work well with python (or any other coding language). there are a whole bunch of API's and permissions to achieve before code can work.

Comment: Yes indeed, that is my question. There is no API call for searching as there is for sending / receive, getting labels etc The documentation only lists a GET call.

Comment: P.S. Formatting corrected